# Does the Pycaret library offer any built-in functionality or options that allow users to include L1 or L2 regularizers?

Tags: python, pycaret

I have two questions:
If we have a binary classifier can we connect it to Pycaret?
I wonder whether Pycaret includes an option to incorporate L1 or L2 regularizers, or any other regularizers, when training binary classifiers?